# CSS animations insert word within an H1

Tags: css, animation, css-transitions

Hi I have a situation where I need to show a word with a transition after some time inside a paragraph

for example i have an:

`<h2>Click here to find <span class="more">more</span> information </h2>`

I need the text more to appear with a sort of "fade" while the left and side text moves a bit to the sides kind of like this effect:

[example](http://jsbin.com/wixaqeteso/edit?html,css,js,output)

What i've tought (and was working) was using another span tag with class spacer right before the .more

```
<h2>Click here to find <span class="spacer"></span><span class="more">more</span> information </h2>
```

This is absolutely positioned and using a transition from width 0 to width 70px
 and was looking fine in every browser except safari, because the spacer is always visible

here is my css code:

```
h2.sides-styled { left:0; margin: 0 auto; opacity:0; overflow: hidden; padding: 4px 0; position: absolute; right: 0; width: 774px; z-index: 1000; }
```

And the spans:

```
span.more { color:red;  font-style: italic;  left:365px; opacity:0; position: absolute; transition: visibility 2s; transition-delay: 3.3s; visibility: hidden; }

span.more.visible { opacity: 1; visibility: visible; }

span.spacer{ width:0; background: blue; -webkit-transition: width 2s ease; -moz-transition: width 0.3s ease; -o-transition: width 0.3s ease; -ms-transition: width 0.3s; transition: width 0.3s;  transition-delay: 3.1s; -webkit-transition-delay: 3.1s; -moz-transition-delay: 3.1s; -o-transition-delay: 3.1s; -ms-transition-delay: 3.1s; }
```

Animation is triggered adding the class .visible in Javascript

I need to achieve this using only css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the effect using CSS3 transitions:

```js
function toggleVisible() {
var heading = document.getElementsByTagName('h2')[0];
heading.classList.toggle('visible');
}

var button = document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0];
button.addEventListener('click', toggleVisible, false);
```

```css
h2 {
font-size: 36px;
text-align: center;
}

h2 span {
display: inline-block;
}

h2 span:nth-of-type(1) {
transform: translateX(42px);
transition: transform 2s ease-in-out;
}

h2 span:nth-of-type(2) {
opacity: 0;
transition: opacity 2s ease-in-out 1s;
}

h2 span:nth-of-type(3) {
transform: translateX(-42px);
transition: transform 2s ease-in-out;
}

h2.visible span:nth-of-type(1) {
transform: translateX(0);
}

h2.visible span:nth-of-type(2) {
opacity: 1;
}

h2.visible span:nth-of-type(3) {
transform: translateX(0);
}
```

```html
<h2><span>Click here to find</span> <span>more</span> <span>information</span></h2>

<button type="button">Toggle visible</button>
```

Comment: This solution seems pretty good, gonna try it on my project and let you know

Comment: I forgot to mention that my H2 was being animated too, when i put that with your code, the translation stops working, take a look at this codepen

http://codepen.io/dannygm/pen/QyVvrd

Comment: I'm looking at the codepen, but I can't see what the problem is...?

Comment: Sorry pal i was working on it and forgot to fork, I got it fixed now thanks to you :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use keyframes for that. I've made a quick test: http://jsbin.com/pubicabiku/1 . **You'll need to adjust *duration* and *position***, but you can get the gist.

More info about keyframes: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-keyframes.asp

**Update**:

For smooth animation, you can use percentages. *from* and *to* represent 0 and 100:

```
/* sleft */
@-webkit-keyframes sleft {
    0% {left: 50px; }
    60% {left: 0px;}
  100% {left: 50px;} // initial state
}
```

To repeat animation X times:

```
animation-iterantion-count: X;
-webkit-animation-iterantion-count: X;
```

***Edit***: I posted the code, just in case:

**CSS**

```
#swap {
  position:absolute;
  color:chocolate;
  -webkit-animation: swap 2s infinite;
   animation: swap 2s infinite;
}

/* swap */
@-webkit-keyframes swap {
    from {left: 150px; opacity:0;}
    to {left: 190px; opacity:1;}
}

@keyframes swap {
    from {left: 150px; opacity:0;}
    to {left: 190px; opacity:1;}
}

#sleft {
  position:absolute;
  -webkit-animation: sleft 2.5s infinite;
   animation: sleft 2.5s infinite;
}

/* sleft */
@-webkit-keyframes sleft {
    from {left: 50px; }
    to {left: 0px;}
}

@keyframes sleft {
    from {left: 50px;}
    to {left: 0px;}
}

#sright {
  position:absolute;
  -webkit-animation: sright 3s infinite;
   animation: sright 3s infinite;
}

/* sright */
@-webkit-keyframes sright {
    from {left: 200px; }
    to {left: 270px;}
}

@keyframes sright {
    from {left: 200px; }
    to {left: 270px;}
}
```

**HTML**

```
<p id="sentence">
    <span id="sleft">We provide</span>
    <span id="swap">code</span> 
    <span id="sright">for your business.</span>
  </p>
```

Comment: HI, thanks but that's not what i'm trying to achieve, and the animation looks odd

Comment: Can you perhaps modify it to not work in a loop? just expand, show text and stay like that

Comment: You can use percentages in @keyframes to make smooth animation.

Comment: Also, for do it only once, add -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;